# Multiple arguments on applicatives not working?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

So I'm trying to learn about monads, functors and applicatives. I've created the following renamed mirror match of `Maybe` called `Sometimes`. (I did this to learn about these things)

```
data Sometimes a = Nope | Thing a deriving Show

instance Monad Sometimes where
    (Thing x) >>= f = f x
    Nope  >>= f = Nope
    return      = Thing

instance Applicative Sometimes where
      pure = Thing
      Nope <*> _ = Nope
      (Thing g) <*> mx = fmap g mx

instance Functor Sometimes where
     fmap _ Nope = Nope
     fmap g (Thing x) = Thing (g x)
```

So when I do the following it works:

```
pure (1+) <*> (Thing 1)
> Thing 2

pure (+) <*> (Thing 1) <*> (Thing 1)
> Thing 2
```

But if I try three additions it doesn't work:

```
pure (+) <*> (Thing 1) <*> (pure 1) <*> (pure 1)

<interactive>:108:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b. (Num (a -> b), Num a) => Sometimes b
```

Why doesn't this work? I would expect the first two to be applied and then the third to be applied to the result of the first two. My book talks about how implementing `fmap0, fmap1, fmap2...` is inefficient and  as such

> ... for functions with any desired number of arguments can be constructed in terms of two basic functions with the following types:
>   `pure :: a -> f a`
>   `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

And states further on:

> A typical use of `pure` and `<*>` has the following form:
>
> ```
> pure g <*> x1 <*> x2 <*> ... <*> xn
> ```

As such I'm expecting it to work but I'm clearly missing something in my definitions/usage of the `Applicative`.

---

I'm using the book Programming in Haskell SE by Graham Hutton

Comment: The reason this does not work is because `(+)` sums two numbers, not three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `(+)` sums two numbers, not three.

You can make a function that sums three numbers, for example with:

```
pure (\x y z -> x+y+z) <*> (Thing 1) <*> (pure 1) <*> (pure 1)
```

this then gives us:

```
Prelude> pure (\x y z -> x+y+z) <*> (Thing 1) <*> (pure 1) <*> (pure 1)
Thing 3
```

> Why doesn't this work? I would expect the first two to be applied and then the third to be applied to the result of the first two.

**Exactly**, but after the first two are applied, this is no longer a function, but a `Num a => Sometimes a`. Indeed, if we determines the types, we see that `Thing (+) :: Num a => Sometimes (a -> a -> a)` and `Thing 1 :: Num b => Sometimes b`, so that means that `Thing (+) <*> Thing 1` has type `Num a => Sometimes (a -> a)`.

Then we determine the type of `Thing (+) <*> Thing 1 <*> Thing 1`, since `Thing (+) <*> Thing 1` has type `Num a => Sometimes (a -> a)`, and the last `Thing 1` has type `Num c => Sometimes c`, it means that `Thing (+) <*> Thing 1 <*> Thing 1` has type `Num a => Sometimes a`, but this is not a function, unless there is a `Num` type that is a function, which is what the error is saying.

Comment: Aha this must be use of partial function application (currying)? `g <*> a <*> b` will result in `(g a) <*> b` and thus a `g a b`?

Comment: @TarickWelling: well `Thing g <*> Thing a <*> Thing b` will result in `Thing (g a b)`, indeed.